# How to use data attributes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add a long shadow by adding css styling with jQuery for any elemet has data-shadow attributes. the shadow color will be the value of the elemet. So this is my try:

```
<div data-shadow="#A00909">Test</div>
```

```
div{
    background:red;
    display:inner-block;
    font-size:44px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff;
    padding:40px;    
    overflow:hidden;
    width:50%;
    margin:auto;
}
```

```
// jQuery
$(function() {

    $( "*" ).attr( "data-shadow", function( i, value ) {
        var t = $(this).data('shadow');
        var n, sh = "",long = 90;        
        for( n = 1 ; n <= long ; n++ ){
            sh = sh + n + "px "+n+"px "+ value; 
            if( n != long ) sh = sh +", ";
        }

        $(this).css("text-shadow",sh);

    });

});
```

in the jQuery code I'm trying to get the value of `data-shadow` but without success.
Otherwise, when I use a specified value like in the following code - it works:

```
$( "*" ).attr( "data-shadow", function( i, value ) {
    var temp = "#A00909";
    var t = $(this).data('shadow');
    var n, sh = "",long = 90;        
    for( n = 1 ; n <= long ; n++ ){
        sh = sh + n + "px "+n+"px "+ temp; 
        if( n != long ) sh = sh +", ";
    }

    $(this).css("text-shadow",sh);

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b0fpkccf/

How to use the value of `data-shadow` instead of temp value for each element has `data-shadow` attributes?

Comment: Hey, looks like it's working to me. However you are using temp not t in your for loop? Try sh = sh + n + "px "+n+"px "+ t; - Also to see it easier use a different colour in your data-shadow.

Comment: You can use `$('[data-shadow]')` instead of `$('*')` as the selector also

Comment: it's not working with t. Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/b0fpkccf/3/

Comment: That fails because there is a missing function print_r(t);

Comment: The * selector is wrong because it's dragging up all sorts - that's why elzi has it correct to use a specific selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close! First, instead of doing a query selector of all `*`, you can use an `attribute selector`.

After that, you'll just call `each` as you were doing (rather than `attr`).

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jpattishalljr/b0fpkccf/4/

```
$(function() {
    $('[data-shadow]').each(function(i, value) {
        var t = $(this).data('shadow');
        var n, sh = "",long = 90;        
        for( n = 1 ; n <= long ; n++ ){
            sh = sh + n + "px "+n+"px "+ t; 
            if( n != long ) sh = sh +", ";
        }

        $(this).css("text-shadow",sh);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/b0fpkccf/5/)

You can go for the `$("[data-shadow]")` selector (as suggested by Jack) and access directly the element's `.css()` callback (cause `$()`) is already a collection of elements:

```
$('[data-shadow]').css("text-shadow", function() {
    var t=$(this).data().shadow, sh="", long=90;        
    for(var n=1; n<=long; n++) sh += n+"px "+n+"px "+t+(n<long?" ,":""); 
    return sh;
});
```

Comment: Great point! jQuery's `implicit iteration` is a wonderful thing!